# Paypal sandbox doesn't recognize freshly returned ProfileID (error 11546)

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've sucesfully integrated paypal's express checkout and IPN notifications, therefore I have problem with recurring payments. I use NVP API to make request with method: CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile it goes well and returns profileId (eg I-GK8NCPH2N712). and profileStatus (eg. ActiveProfile). But when I request GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails with this profileId I get error 11546 with description:

Profile ID is not valid for this account.  Please resubmit request with the correct profile ID.

I've checked that profileId is correct at the buyer and also seller page in history.

Is it an issue with sandbox environment? Or maybe is it something that profile start is delayed in time, it will start after one month (property PROFILESTARTDATE)? Or maybe a merchant can't access recurring payment, but that would be pretty disaster.

Please share any ideas, what to check or what could it be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem after reading article of Derek MacDonald:

http://derekmd.com/2009/02/paypal-development-the-art-of-obfuscation/

Problem was that I had created profile using API credentials of one seller and then tried to do something using another seller with different credentials.

Stupid fool of me, but as Derek MacDonald wrote, error message could be a bit more informative...